# Scrollview inside DrawerLayout prevents ListView buttons from working

Tags: android, xml

How can I revise this xml file to have my navigation drawer buttons work as well? Most other rearrangements with scrollview layouts and DrawerLayouts crash the app immediately.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >


     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <ListView android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee"
            />


         <ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout 
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#C2DFFF">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/indigo_100"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:text="2nd SCREEN" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/i1x2" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/dungeon_1_2"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to move the `ListView` to after the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @MikeM. Wow you're a lifesaver. I spent over an hour trying to figure out how to fix this....

Comment: No problem. Yeah, whichever `View` you use as the drawer needs to be listed last in the `DrawerLayout`. Otherwise, it's z-ordered under the content `View`, which is why you couldn't click it. Gimme a minute, and I'll find a duplicate we can close this with. Or, did you just wanna delete this?

Comment: @MikeM. Hmm duplicate might be best. I've been searching for a bit on SO as well, but couldn't find the answer I was looking for.